# .htaccess 302 redirects with regular expression replacement

Tags: regex, .htaccess, seo

I have search webstie where users type in following query in the url and do a search.

```
http://www.example.com/?search=key word&type=sin
http://www.example.com/?search=key word
```

I am doing a canonical link in the page to avoid these being indexed in the goodle.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/key-word/"/>
```

however i need to add a 302 redirect as well to this. i.e

```
Redirect 302 / http://www.example.com/key-word/ (key word is replaced spaces to hypen)
```

how do i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?search=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

## replace of space with -

# executes **repeatedly** as long as there are more than 1 spaces in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*) +(\S* .*)$" /$1-$2 [L,NE]

# executes when there is exactly 1 space in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*) (\S*)$" /$1-$2? [L,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: There was a typo, it is fixed now.

Comment: now it redirects but seems to add query string like this "xyz.com/key-word/?search=key word"

Comment: That's not true actually. `?` in the end of `/%1?` in target of first rule strips off query string.

Comment: may be its one of my other rules causing the problems is this caused this problem 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Now this works for "key words" but not for "key"  second keyword with no replacements it still results in http://www.example.com/key/?search=key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65493/discussion-between-anubhava-and-mahen3d).